# HTTP trace in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

Is there an easy way in Wireshark to convert set of http request/responses to set of text files?
each file containing either request or response.
I can easily do this with Fiddler but have not found how to do this in Wireshark.

Comment: Have you tried "file->export objects->HTTP" ?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but the exported file is in specific format which is not easy to use in my own application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

1. Only open File> export objects> HTTP

A window should Open. Then click the Export All button.
Text files, pictures and scripts should export.